# In HuggingFace tokenizers: how can I split a sequence simply on spaces?

Tags: split, tokenize, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am using `DistilBertTokenizer` tokenizer from [HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co).

I would like to tokenize my text by simple splitting it on space:

```
["Don't", "you", "love", "", "Transformers?", "We", "sure", "do."]
```

instead of the default behavior, which is like this:

```
["Do", "n't", "you", "love", "", "Transformers", "?", "We", "sure", "do", "."]
```

I read their documentation about [Tokenization](https://huggingface.co/transformers/tokenizer_summary.html) in general as well as about [BERT Tokenizer](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#transformers.BertTokenizer) specifically, but could not find an answer to this simple question :(

I assume that it should be a parameter when loading Tokenizer, but I could not find it among the parameters list ...

EDIT:
Minimal code example to reproduce:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-cased')

tokens = tokenizer.tokenize("Don't you love  Transformers? We sure do.")
print("Tokens: ", tokens)
```

Comment: Try passing `sep_token=' '`, or setting `tokenizer.sep_token = ' '`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I tried, didn't help. Unfortunately. Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how it works. The transformers library provides different types of [tokenizers](https://huggingface.co/transformers/tokenizer_summary.html). In the case of distilbert it is a [wordpiece tokenizer](https://huggingface.co/transformers/tokenizer_summary.html#wordpiece) that has a defined vocabulary that was used to train the corresponding model and therefore does not offer such modifications (as far as I know). Something you can do is using the [split()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) method of the python string:

```py
text = "Don't you love  Transformers? We sure do."
tokens = text.split()
print("Tokens: ", tokens)
```

Output:

```
Tokens:  ["Don't", 'you', 'love', '', 'Transformers?', 'We', 'sure', 'do.']
```

In case you are looking for a bit more complex tokenization that also takes the punctuation into account, you can utilize the basic_tokenizer:

```py
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer

tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-cased')
tokens = tokenizer.basic_tokenizer.tokenize(text)
print("Tokens: ", tokens)
```

Output:

```
Tokens:  ['Don', "'", 't', 'you', 'love', '', 'Transformers', '?', 'We', 'sure', 'do', '.']
```

Comment: That sounds great. Thank you for the tip, @cronoik. And so I could encode a sentence using BERT after I split it into tokens myself, right?

Comment: @TarasKucherenko: It depends. You can for example train your own BERT with whitespace tokenization or any other approach. But when you use a pre-trained BERT you have to use the same tokenization algorithm, because a pre-trained model has learned vector representations for each token and you can not simply change the tokenization approach without losing the benefit of a pre-trained model.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this does not do what I wanted as pointed out in the comments.

Here is one idea I have tried:

```py
from transformers import DistilBertModel, DistilBertTokenizer
import torch

text_str = "also du fängst an mit der Stadtrundfahrt"

# create DistilBERT tokenizer and model
tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-german-cased')
model = DistilBertModel.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-german-cased')

# check if tokens are correct
tokens = tokenizer.basic_tokenizer.tokenize(text_str)
print("Tokens: ", tokens)

# Encode the curent text
input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode(tokens)).unsqueeze(0)
outputs = model(input_ids)
last_hidden_states = outputs[0]
print(last_hidden_states.shape)
print(last_hidden_states[0,1:-1].shape)

print(last_hidden_states)
```

The key is to split on tokens first using `BasicTokenizer` (as proposed by @cronoik) and then use already tokenized text when encoding it.

Comment: Not sure if you are aware of it but I think this is not what you want to do. Please check the output of `tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids.tolist()[0])`. What you see here is, that `fängst` and `Stadtrundfahrt` are encoded with the same id because they are not part of the dictionary. @TarasKucherenko

Comment: Oh, yes, you are absolutely right, @cronoik . So it seems that what I want is indeed not possible yet. I open an issue request for it: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/10058

Comment: It is not like that they need to modify their code to make that possible. What you are requesting is a full dictionary transformer. You can use each of their transformers models, but you need to train them by yourself. There is no pre-trained model available as far as I know. According to this [website](https://www.welt.de/kultur/article124064744/Die-deutsche-Sprache-hat-5-3-Millionen-Woerter.html), it would require 5.3 million entries. There are very good reasons (e.g. training data, training time) why subword tokenization is the current state of the art approach.

Comment: Right, good point @cronoik. I edited this proposed answer to reflect it.